# Can you use HTML entities in JSON-LD?

Tags: html, json, html-entities, json-ld, structured-data

I am planning to add JSON-LD on some web pages and some have the letter enye (`ñ`). I had previously replaced the letter  with the HTML entity `&#241;`, but later realized the `ñ` in the JSON-LDwas also replaced. Is this valid JSON-LD, and will it not cause errors in Google if rich results will be generated:

```
{
 "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "Place",
  "name": "Santo Ni&#241;o"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using entities is fine in embedded JSON-LD, as it is still a valid JSON string, however do not expect the entities to be replaced with their UTF-8 equivalents. As described in [Section 7.2 of the JSON-LD Syntax spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld11/#restrictions-for-contents-of-json-ld-script-elements)

> Authors should avoid using character sequences in scripts embedded in
> HTML which may be confused with a comment-open, script-open,
> comment-close, or script-close.
>
> NOTE
>
> Such content should be escaped as indicated below, however the
> content will remain escaped after processing through the JSON-LD API.

This is an HTML processing rule for data script elements, and not specific to JSON-LD.